# How to change click button to window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using https://jquerymodal.com to show a modal dialog in my home page. But I read in documentation:

> Create a link with **rel="modal:open"** and set the href attribute to the modal's DOM id.

I´ve try  change the interaction from click button to window load with:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#tour-virtual').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

I am new with javascript and I don´t know how to make this change. 
Could you help me please?

Comment: Refer to the documentation - https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#opening

Comment: Anchor id will call the modal you don't need to write jQuery code until and unless you required some extra property.
You may check out this [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoXNJy](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoXNJy) and read the document [Documentation](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)

Answer (score 0):

You can  do like:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#tour-virtual').modal('show');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>


<div id="tour-virtual" class="modal">
  <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>  
</div>
```